# Need to remove backslashes from json value

Tags: php, json, web-services, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I need to remove `\` from the codeigniter, 
this is my output:

```
{
    "id": "3496",
    "label": "B\\'less S\\'On Chicken Leg 200-240g",
    "sku": "",
    "cat_id": "72",
    "slug": "b-less-s-on-chicken-leg-200-240g",
    "product_min_order_qty": "1",
    "product_unit_type": "pkt",
    "alter_unit_type": "",
    "product_short_desc": null,
    "product_long_desc": "B\\'less S\\'On Chicken Leg 200-240g\r\n\r\n8 X 2kg / ctn",
    "image": null
}
```

Below is my code:

```
$product_res = $this->Mydb->get_all_records('*', 'table_name');
$responseData = array("status" => 'ok',"categories" => $category_res,"products" => $product_res,"search_count" => $search_count, "Response" => array("response" => "Success", "response_code" => 1));    
$this->output->set_content_type('application/json;'); 
$this->output->set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
return $this->output->set_output(json_encode($responseData,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

Comment: How about `str_replace`?

Comment: why? the back sashes are escaping

Comment: @TobiasF.  need to remove the array...!! i have tried str_replace,stripslashes , mysqli_real_escape_string but nothing is worked for me

Answer (score 3):

Just use the [stripslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) function

```
return $this->output->set_output(stripslashes(json_encode($responseData,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)));
```

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ',' or '}' after property value in object at line 155 column 80 of the JSON data it thrown this error...!!

Comment: @fafpoontha can you show the example content of `$responseData` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var finalData = str.replace(/\\/g, "");
```

Answer (score 1):

try trim function

$responseData = array("status" => 'ok',"categories" => trim($category_res),"products" => trim($product_res),"search_count" => $search_count, "Response" => array("response" => "Success", "response_code" => 1));